# "put-options" and "call-options" vs "puts" and "calls"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Do we need [puts](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puts) and [calls](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calls) when we already have [put-options](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/put-options) and [call-options](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-options)?

Not all puts and calls have to do with options (e.g. there are put warrants, call warrants, puttable bonds, callable bonds, etc.), but it looks like all the existing questions in the "puts" and "calls" tags are about options.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

1. Move all the "puts" and "calls" questions into "put-options" and "call-options".

   Reasoning: All "puts" and "calls" questions are currently about options. It makes little sense to have multiple tags that deal with exactly the same topic. I don't think tag synonyms are appropriate, because there are legitimate uses of "puts" and "calls" outside options.
2. Delete the "puts" and "calls" tags.

   Reasoning: The generic "puts" and "calls" tags should be deleted because they are too tempting to use for options. For uses outside options, there is currently no demand so deletion is safe. To avoid the use of "puts" and "calls" in the future, instrument-specific tags could be created when the need arises (e.g. "put-warrants", "callable-bonds", etc.).

Comment: Unless I've misremembered/misunderstood what's possible, it's hard to truly "delete" a tag. We can remove all current usage but someone with enough rep can just recreate it when writing a question. We need help from SE staff to actively blacklist a tag to stop it ever being used and it's unlikely to be worth it for a small case like this. On the other hand a synonym is a bit like deleting in that when someone tries to use "puts" they get "put-options" instead - so the tag can't be used but people are always directed towards one specific alternative. As you say it's not perfect for this case.

Comment: Any progress on this?  The current setup is confusing.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket the solution exactly as proposed is unimplementable, as far as I know. Would people be happy with a synonym as an imperfect approximation?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Yes, a synonym is fine. :)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket ok done